# How do I find the relevant command for something in linux?

Tags: linux, man

For example, say I'm trying to find the command that displays the routing table (like `route`) or to run a `traceroute`, but I don't actually know the commands that accomplish this.  My understanding is that I should be able to use `man -k [word]`, but it never seems to work: if I do `man -k route` on Scientific Linux 6.1, I get no results, even though I would expect it to return anything that includes the word "route" in it!

Unfortunately, when I search for the answer to this, it's confounded by people explaining the `find` command for a file search.

Thank you!

Comment: I get 6 results for `man -k route` (which, incidentally, is the same as `apropos route`), including `route(8)`. Do you have the relevant man pages installed?

Comment: I get 10 results. In addition to what Michael Mrozek said, do you actually have the programs (`tracerout`, `iproute`, `route`, etc.) installed too?

Comment: I do have the commands installed, and I can "man route", but for some reason no results for man -k route.  Is there a way to rebuild the man -k index or something?  Thanks again.

Comment: One can do things like package searching, but this is somewhat distribution dependent. What distribution do you use, please?

Answer (score 4):

The command `/usr/bin/mandb` will rebuild the man database on Linux. This should be set up as a cronjob. On other Unixes use the comamnd `catman -w`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!  While these commands didn't work for me, they got me on the path to finding the one that did: "makewhatis".  After running makewhatis, I now get 10 results for man -k route.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look `apropos`:

```
runejuhl@lapaz:~$ apropos apropos 
apropos (1)          - search the manual page names and descriptions
```

From my system:

```
runejuhl@lapaz:~$ apropos route
ip-mroute (8)        - (unknown subject)
ip-route (8)         - (unknown subject)
lft (1)              - print the route packets trace to network host
lft.db (1)           - print the route packets trace to network host
NETLINK_ROUTE (7)    - Linux IPv4 routing socket
route (8)            - show / manipulate the IP routing table
routef (8)           - flush routes
routel (8)           - list routes with pretty output format
tcptraceroute (1)    - A traceroute implementation using TCP packets
tcptraceroute (8)    - print the route packets trace to network host
tcptraceroute.db (8) - print the route packets trace to network host
tcptraceroute.mt (1) - A traceroute implementation using TCP packets
traceproto (1)       - print the route packets trace to network host
traceproto.db (1)    - print the route packets trace to network host
traceroute (1)       - print the route packets trace to network host
traceroute-nanog (1) - print the route packets trace to network host
traceroute.db (1)    - print the route packets trace to network host
traceroute6 (1)      - print the route packets trace to network host
traceroute6.db (1)   - print the route packets trace to network host
```

Comment: `apropos` is equivalent to `man -k`, which the OP already mentioned.

Comment: Dang, you're right. Next time I'll read the answers all the way through :)